# mq_timedreceive reporting EAGAIN error with O_NONBLOCK not set

Tags: c, unix, ipc, qnx

The `timespec` sent to the `mq_timedreceive` is set to be 20 seconds. After 20 seconds has elapsed, the `errno` returns "Resource temporarily unavailable" (`EAGAIN`). Furthermore this sends a signal and crashes the process. What I am expecting to happen is a `ETIMEDOUT` response and my code to keep executing. I have made sure that the queue is not with with `O_NONBLOCK` so there shouldn't be a reason why for `EAGAIN`

```
event_type get_event_timed(mqd_t channel, struct timespec ts) {
    //get timed touch event from devi-atmel-mxt
    ssize_t ret = -1;
    char Buffer[ASYNC_BUFFER_SIZE] = {0};

    event_type *event;

    //mq_monotonic will block for duration specfifed by timespec
    //will return -1 && ETIMEDOUT if no event withing duration
    ret = mq_timedreceive(channel, Buffer, ASYNC_BUFFER_SIZE, NULL, &ts);
    if ((-1 == ret) && (errno == ETIMEDOUT)) {
        slogf(_SLOGC_INPUT, _SLOG_ERROR, "[ASYNC_LOGGER] %s TIMEDOUT\n", __func__);
        //return TIMEDOUT
        *event = TIMEDOUT;
    }
    else if (-1 == ret) {
        slogf(_SLOGC_INPUT, _SLOG_ERROR, "[ASYNC_LOGGER] %s error: %s\n", __func__, strerror(errno));
        //return ERROR
        *event = ERROR;
    }
    else {
        //printf("mq_recieve sucess\n");
        slogf(_SLOGC_INPUT, _SLOG_ERROR, "[ASYNC_LOGGER] get_event_timed: mq_recieve success\n");
        //casting buffer into event_type
        event = (event_type *)Buffer;
    }
    slogf(_SLOGC_INPUT, _SLOG_ERROR, "[ASYNC_LOGGER] %s buffer is: %d\n", __func__, *event);
    return *event;
}
```

Comment: Please share the code with mq_open().

Answer (score 0):

This is a know bug in QNX. Due to the fact that the queue also empty at the same time, the mq cannot know between ETIMEDOUT and O_NONBLOCK.